# Linear operator problem: $T^n=0$ and $T^{n-1}\neq0$

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Problem:
Let $T$ be a linear operator.

$T\in L(V).$

$\dim V=n<\infty$

$T^n=0,T^{n-1}\neq0$

---

Prove that $$r(T)=n-1$$
My try: if $r(T)=n-1$ then $d(t)=1$.

And I also know that $r(T^2)\leq r(T)$

Comment: Could you please define $r(T)$ and $d(t)$? I have never seen such convention before.

Comment: I would assume $r$ means rank and $d$ means determinant, but then $d(T)$ should be 0 instead of 1...

Comment: @DanShved It could be the nullity of $T$, perhaps?

Comment: @BigbearZzz Could be... But really, the OP should clarify this.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Since $T^{n-1}\ne0$then let $x_0\in V$ such that $T^{n-1}(x_0)\ne0$. Now prove that the vectors $x_0,T(x_0),\ldots,T^{n-1}(x_0)$ are linearly independent and so they form a basis $\mathcal B$ of $V$ (why?). What's the matrix of $T$ relative to $\mathcal B$? What's its rank?

Comment: Why vectors x0,T(x0),...,t^n-1(x0) is linearly independent?

Answer (score 2):

Here is an abstract approach that solves the problem without ever looking at specific vectors. Consider this chain of subspaces of $V$:
$$
V \supseteq T(V) \supseteq T^2(V) \supseteq \ldots \supseteq T^{n-1}(V) \supseteq T^n(V) = \{0\}.
$$

Since $\operatorname{rank}(T) = \dim T(V)$, we need to prove that $\dim T(V) = n-1$. We do this in two steps.

1. Each inclusion in this chain is proper, i.e. you can replace all $\supseteq$ signs with $\supset$. Otherwise, if we had $T^{i-1}(V) = T^{i}(V)$ for some $1 < i \leq n$, then applying $T^{n-i}$ on both sides would give us $T^{n-1}(V) = T^{n}(V)$. But this is a contradiction, because $T^{n-1}(V) \neq \{0\}$ and $T^n(V)=\{0\}$.
2. Since each inclusion is proper, we have $$n = \dim V > \dim T(V) > \dim T^2(V) > \ldots > \dim T^n(V) = 0,$$ and the only way this can be is if $\dim T(V) = n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $M_T(\lambda)=\lambda^n$ and $C_T(\lambda)=\lambda^n$.Try making the jordan canonical form using this..where $M_T (\lambda) $ and $C_T (\lambda)$ are the minimal.and characterstic polynomial respectively